# why function inside function doesn't need parentheses? javascript?

Tags: ajax, function, parentheses

[image]

I'm trying to learn ajax from online tutorial, but i don't understand on line 20,
why doesn't handleServiceResponse function have parentheses()?
and why won't it work with parentheses?

Thanks so much, you guys here are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
function handleServerResponse() {
   ...
}
```

is the same as:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   ...
}
```

In this case, `onreadystatechange` expects to be set as a function definition.

---

To demonstrate a usage where you could use parentheses here, here is an example:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = generateServerResponseHandler();
function generateServerResponseHandler() {
    return function() {
        ...
    };
}
```

You can see that the function `generateServerResponseHandler` is called immediately, but `onreadystatechange` is still set to a function definition.

---

In JavaScript, functions are "first class citizens". Wikipedia has an excellent writeup: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Comment: xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse; means onreadystatechange stores function handleServerResponse?

Comment: Yes, it acts like a pointer to that function. In JavaScript, functions are "first class citizens". Wikipedia has an excellent writeup: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function